# Get fast count after join on "containment" expression

Tags: postgresql, database-design, join, postgresql-performance, index-tuning

I have three tables in a PostgreSQL database that I'm querying via a view and some joins.

```
CREATE TABLE network_info (
  network         CIDR          NOT NULL,
  some_info       TEXT          NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (network)
);

CREATE TABLE ipaddr_info (
  ipaddr          INET          NOT NULL,
  some_info       INT           NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ipaddr, some_info)
);

CREATE TABLE ipaddrs (
  addr            INET          NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (addr)
);

CREATE VIEW ipaddr_summary AS
SELECT DISTINCT
  i.addr                  AS ip_address,
  a.some_info             AS network_info,
  COUNT(b.ipaddr)         AS ip_info_count
FROM ipaddrs AS i
LEFT JOIN network_info AS a
  ON (i.addr << a.network)
LEFT JOIN ipaddr_info AS b
  ON (i.addr = b.ipaddr)
GROUP BY i.addr, a.some_info
;
```

All of the tables have ~150K rows right now, and it takes a really long time (~3 hours) to run `SELECT * from ipaddr_summary;` on an Intel Pentium 4 2.8GHz dual core with 2G of memory running PostgreSQL 9.3.

Is there a way I can restructure or optimize this particular schema or view to make the query faster, or is it a hardware issue? I'm going to spin up a beefy VM in the cloud and test, but wanted to see if there's a way to optimize w/out just throwing more hardware at it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There *might* be hardware issues, too - how should we know? But there are certainly issues with the query.

**First** of all, remove `DISTINCT` from your `VIEW` definition. It's doing *nothing* at all (but complicating and slowing things down). Related answer on SO with explanation:

- [PostgreSQL - Slow query joining on a VIEW](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28131205/939860)

Arriving at this (cleaned up) query:

```
SELECT i.addr      AS ip_address
     , a.some_info AS network_info
     , COUNT(b.ipaddr) AS ip_info_count
FROM   ipaddrs           i
LEFT   JOIN ipaddr_info  b  ON i.addr = b.ipaddr
LEFT   JOIN network_info a  ON i.addr << a.network
GROUP  BY 1,2;
```

**Next**, the query looks suspiciously like it's going very wrong. Two uncorrelated joins can multiply rows:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860)

With 150k rows in each table, there is potential for a *huge* (unintended) Cartesian product. My **educated guess**, you really want this:

```
SELECT addr        AS ip_address
     , a.some_info AS network_info
     , b.ip_info_count
FROM   ipaddrs i
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT  ipaddr AS addr, count(*) AS ip_info_count
   FROM    ipaddr_info
   GROUP   BY 1
  ) b USING (addr)
LEFT   JOIN network_info a ON i.addr << a.network;
```

I suspect that `GROUP BY` in the outer `SELECT` is not needed now, either. Besides fixing the count, avoiding the proxy cross-join should also be faster by orders of magnitude.

You could first join to `ipaddrs` (especially if you have predicates filtering rows from it) and then aggregate, or first aggregate in the subquery like displayed. Usefulness of this variant largely depends on data distribution. It's great for *few* `ipaddr` with big counts. See:

- [Slow queries related to subqueries using aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54719/slow-queries-related-to-subqueries-using-aggregation/54722#54722)

**Finally**, you need **index support**. Equality between `ipaddr` and `addr` is covered by the default btree indexes of the `PRIMARY KEY`. The query on the whole table is probably using a sequential scan anyway.

For the "is contained by" operator `<<` operator you'll need a GIN or GiST index. The best option would be the new [**`inet_ops`** GiST index operator class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist-builtin-opclasses.html) in Postgres **9.4** (supports data types `inet` and `cidr`):

```
CREATE INDEX ON network_info USING gist (network inet_ops);
```

Not sure if the index can be used in a plain `INNER` (or `OUTER`) join. Can't test right now. *Maybe* you need correlated subqueries or a `LATERAL` join to utilize the index:

```
SELECT addr AS ip_address
     , a.network_info
     , b.ip_info_count
FROM   ipaddrs i
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT  ipaddr AS addr, count(*) AS ip_info_count
   FROM    ipaddr_info
   GROUP   BY 1
  ) b USING (addr)
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT some_info AS network_info
   FROM   network_info
   WHERE  network >> i.addr
   ) a ON true;
```

For indexing in older versions see:

- [PostgreSQL field data type for IPv4 addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15384179/939860)

Comment: Thanks! FYI, the GiST indexes are what really added a performance boost... your suggested select statement saved ~2 seconds on the 8 core, 30G Google Cloud VM with PostgreSQL 9.4 I spun up to test. The GiST indexes provided an additional ~242 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your << is not utilizing an index, because your primary key would create a btree index, and what you need to make that particular operation indexable is a gist index. (use explain analyze to confirm).  if that is the case that index not being used,

Try doing something like

```
   CREATE INDEX idx_network_info_network_gist
     ON network_info USING gist(network inet_ops); 

 CREATE INDEX idx_ipaddr_info_ipaddr_gist
    ON ipaddr_info USING gist(ipaddr inet_ops);
```

and doing similar with your addr and ipaddr columns.

Comment: Thanks! If you can, take a look at https://gist.github.com/activeshadow/2e14bf889d9d216713b6 to see the errors I got when trying to add a gist index for the CIDR and INET types. Ideas?

Comment: Weird -- I guess I was able to run the command because I had btree_gist extension installed.  It seems even though there is a gist index class, it's not marked as default, so you need to do this.  I've ammended my above.

Comment: I was a bit incorrect in my assessment. I guess that operator can use a btree index though the gist version was introduced in 9.4 and should be better.  Here is an article detailing why it's not the default: http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-gist-inet-datatype/