# Postgres datetime sort slow and not using index

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning, performance, sorting, postgresql-performance

Using Postgres 9.4, I'm trying to order a query by an indexed datetime column.

```
explain 
SELECT g.*, array_agg(gp.platform_id) as platform_list,
            array_agg(gm.metacritic_id) as metacritic_list,
            array_agg(gr.review_id) as review_list,
            array_agg(gn.genre_id) as genre_list,
            array_agg(gp.id) as release_list 
FROM gb_game g 
LEFT JOIN gb_release gp ON g.id = gp.game_id 
LEFT JOIN gb_game_metacritic gm ON g.id = gm.game_id 
LEFT JOIN gb_game_reviews gr ON g.id = gr.game_id 
LEFT JOIN gb_game_genre gn ON g.id = gn.game_id 
GROUP BY g.id 
ORDER BY g.release_date 
DESC limit 25 offset 0

Limit  (cost=66391.46..66391.52 rows=25 width=294)
  ->  Sort  (cost=66391.46..66511.58 rows=48051 width=294)
        Sort Key: g.release_date
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1.56..65035.49 rows=48051 width=294)
              Group Key: g.id
              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1.56..53579.05 rows=691686 width=294)
                    Merge Cond: (g.id = gn.game_id)
                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1.14..16374.78 rows=63464 width=290)
                          Merge Cond: (g.id = gp.game_id)
                          ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.85..10856.60 rows=48051 width=282)
                                Merge Cond: (g.id = gr.game_id)
                                ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.58..10676.85 rows=48051 width=278)
                                      Merge Cond: (g.id = gm.game_id)
                                      ->  Index Scan using platforms_game_pkey on gb_game g  (cost=0.29..8984.87 rows=48051 width=274)
                                      ->  Index Scan using gb_game_metacritic_6072f8b3 on gb_game_metacritic gm  (cost=0.29..1264.75 rows=24569 width=8)
                                ->  Index Scan using gb_game_reviews_6072f8b3 on gb_game_reviews gr  (cost=0.28..51.04 rows=686 width=8)
                          ->  Index Scan using platforms_release_6072f8b3 on gb_release gp  (cost=0.29..4604.75 rows=63464 width=12)
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.42..27979.58 rows=523702 width=8)
                          ->  Index Scan using gb_game_genre_6072f8b3 on gb_game_genre gn  (cost=0.42..26670.33 rows=523702 width=8)
```

The `release_date` column doesn't have many repeats other than null.
Everything is fast until the final sort.

Is there a special kind of index I need to use to speed up this query?

Comment: Can you put up explain (analyze, buffers)?

Comment: Information is missing. Please consider instructions in the [tag info for \[postgresql-performance\]](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Answer (score 2):

#### Better query

Seems like a perfect occasion for a couple of `LATERAL` joins, which should be ***much*** faster here:

```
SELECT g.*, p.platform_list, m.metacritic_list
     , r.review_list, n.genre_list, p.release_list 
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   gb_game
   ORDER  BY release_date DESC NULLS LAST  -- !? see below
   LIMIT  25
   OFFSET 0
   ) g
,      LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(platform_id) AS platform_list
        , array_agg(id)          AS release_list 
   FROM   gb_release
   WHERE  game_id = g.id
   ) p
,      LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT metacritic_id
      FROM   gb_game_metacritic
      WHERE  game_id = g.id)     AS metacritic_list
   ) m
,      LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT review_id
      FROM   gb_game_reviews
      WHERE  game_id = g.id)     AS review_list
   ) r
,      LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT genre_id
      FROM   gb_game_genre
      WHERE  game_id = g.id)     AS genre_list
   ) n
ORDER   BY g.release_date DESC NULLS LAST;  -- repeat inner sort order
```

#### Indexes

You need an index on each `game_id` column in the child tables.
Multicolumn indexes might be even better if (and only if) you can get index-only scans out of them:

```
gb_release (game_id, id, platform_id)  -- special: 2 additional columns
gb_game_metacritic (game_id, metacritic_id)
gb_game_reviews (game_id, review_id)
gb_game_genre (game_id, genre_id)
```

The order of columns matters.

And finally, you need an index on `gb_game (release_date)`.
There is no data type called <strike>`datetime`</strike> in Postgres. ***Assuming*** you mean `timestamp` (some ORMs map this way).

Either way, *if* you really *mean* to `ORDER BY g.release_date DESC`, a plain index on `(release_date DESC)` or just `(release_date)` does the job

*If* the column can be NULL, I suspect you actually want to sort NULL values last. Adapt your query like I did to `ORDER BY g.release_date DESC NULLS LAST`. A plain index on `(release_date)` still works, but is not the optimum. Use a matching sort order in your index:

```
gb_game (release_date DESC NULLS LAST)
```

Or (almost equivalent):

```
gb_game (release_date ASC NULLS FIRST)
```

More:

- [Unused index in range of dates query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90128/unused-index-in-range-of-dates-query/90183#90183)
- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)

#### Explain query

You join to *multiple* tables that can have `n` related rows for a single row in `gb_game`, resulting rows in the intermediary derived table are multiplied with every join to multiple rows. That's not only a **major performance issue**, it's also ***incorrect***. Or at least I assume as much while detailed information is missing. Related:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860)
- [Is there a way I can speed up queries against this particular view?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90237/is-there-a-way-i-can-speed-up-queries-against-this-particular-view/90254#90254)

I avoid the problem a priori by aggregating each child table separately in `LATERAL` subqueries. That seems particularly efficient, since you only pick 25 rows total.

While being at it I use a faster `ARRAY` constructor for single column aggregation (while I still use `array_agg()` for the case where two columns from the same table are aggregated separately.

Note that the order of elements in each array is ***arbitrary***. You can add an `ORDER BY` clause in each lateral subquery to determine the order.

The last three lateral subqueries could be replaced with a correlated subqueries:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)