# Join 3 tables with where and sorting clauses

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate, count

I have 3 tables, `vendors`, `vendor_models`and `cameras`. I am trying to get some values from db all of `vendor_models` but name from `vendor` too.

Each `camera` has a reference of `vendor_model` as `model_id`.

10 cameras can have one same `vendor_model`.

I am doing this query

```
SELECT v0."id", v0."vendor_id", v0."exid", v0."name", v0."username",
   v0."password", v0."jpg_url", v0."h264_url",  v0."mjpg_url", v0."mpeg4_url",
   v0."mobile_url", v0."lowres_url", v0."shape", v0."resolution", 
   v0."official_url", v0."more_info", v0."audio_url", v0."poe",
   v0."wifi", v0."upnp", v0."ptz", v0."infrared", v0."varifocal",
   v0."sd_card", v0."audio_io", v0."discontinued", v0."onvif",
   v0."psia", v0."channel", v0."created_at", v0."updated_at"
FROM "vendor_models" AS v0
INNER JOIN "vendors" AS v1 ON v0."vendor_id" = v1."id"
WHERE ((lower(v0."name") LIKE $1))
  OR (lower(v1."name") LIKE $2)
ORDER BY v1."name" ["%%", "%%"]
```

after getting all those values. I am doing another query. such as

```
SELECT c0."id", c0."owner_id", c0."model_id", c0."exid",
   c0."name", c0."timezone", c0."thumbnail_url",
   c0."is_online", c0."offline_reason", c0."is_public",
   c0."is_online_email_owner_notification", c0."alert_emails",
   c0."discoverable", c0."config", c0."mac_address",
   c0."location", c0."last_polled_at", c0."last_online_at",
   c0."created_at", c0."updated_at"
FROM "cameras" AS c0
WHERE (c0."model_id" = $1) [4]
```

which then give me the total number of cameras which are using this model.

my problem is I want to merge this query to in single one.

where I can get all the values of VendorModel as well as vendor. and also the count of cameras which are using each vendor model. which I am unable to do right now any help would be appreciable.

Update:

I have got here

```
SELECT vendor_models.id, vendor_models.name, count(cameras.id) as count 
  FROM "vendor_models" 
  INNER JOIN "vendors" ON "vendor_models"."vendor_id" = "vendors"."id" 
  INNER JOIN "cameras" ON "vendor_models"."id" = "cameras"."model_id"
  GROUP BY vendor_models.id, vendor_models.name
  ORDER BY count desc
```

But I cannot get vendor.name.. can you help?

Update:

```
SELECT vendor_models.id, vendor_models.name, v.name, count(cameras.id) as count 
  FROM vendor_models
  INNER JOIN vendors as v ON vendor_models.vendor_id = v.id 
  INNER JOIN cameras ON vendor_models.id = cameras.model_id
  GROUP BY vendor_models.id, vendor_models.name, v.name
  ORDER BY v.name asc
```

I got the final one. can you help to make it better?

Comment: Next time, please remember to start with your version of Postgres and table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still room for improvement. This is your last version, untangled, formatted and shortened with table aliases:

```
SELECT vm.id, v.name, vm.name, count(c.id) AS count 
FROM   vendors       v
JOIN   vendor_models vm ON vm.vendor_id = v.id 
JOIN   cameras       c  ON c.model_id = vm.id
GROUP  BY vm.id, v.name, vm.name
ORDER  BY v.name;
```

Remaining problems:

- You have the name `name` twice in the result, which is unhelpful to say the least.
  (A shining example why non-descriptive names like "name" are *bad* names.)
- Sort order not fully deterministic.
- Not as fast as it could be.

I suggest:

```
SELECT vm.id
     , v.name AS vendor, vm.name AS model  -- column aliases to disambiguate
     , c.camera_count
FROM   vendors       v
JOIN   vendor_models vm ON vm.vendor_id = v.id 
JOIN  (
   SELECT model_id, count(*) AS camera_count  -- count(*) slightly faster
   FROM   cameras
   GROUP  BY 1           -- aggregate first, join later
   ) c ON c.model_id = vm.id
ORDER  BY v.name, vm.name, vm.id; -- add "id" if the names are not unique
```

If you count cameras per model first, you have far fewer join operations and don't have to aggregate outer columns at all. Should be faster.

[`count(*)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) is a bit faster than `count(expression)` (separate implementation) while doing the same in the absence of NULL values.

Since columns from the outer tables (`vendors`, `vendor_models`) are not aggregated at all now, you can put any of these columns in the `SELECT` list at will - including `vm.*`.

Related:

- [Understanding multiple table join with aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87249/understanding-multiple-table-join-with-aggregation/87479#87479)
- [Slow queries related to subqueries using aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54719/slow-queries-related-to-subqueries-using-aggregation/54722#54722)

Comment: now can i get all vm.*?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq: Yes, that's trivial now, since outer columns are not aggregated at all. Just put it in the `SELECT` list.