# CASE statement not returning expected results

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate, case, aggregate-filter

First time using Postgres and building a query with a `CASE` statement. I am trying to end up with a collection of data whereby one of the columns in the data (`status`) qualifies the row based on conditions.

I have 3 tables in a Postgres DB as follows:

Table `devices`:

| id | serial_number | retired | last_reported_utc_at | other_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1234 | FALSE | 2020-12-01 15:34:23 | ... |
| 5 | 4567 | FALSE | 2020-12-01 15:34:23 | ... |
| 6 | NULL | FALSE | NULL | ... |

Table `device_measurements`:

| id | device_id | reading | read_utc_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1.36 | 2020-12-01 15:34:23 |
| 2 | 2 | 2.45 | 2020-12-12 18:21:12 |
| 3 | 6 | 1.87 | 2020-12-03 20:29:12 |

Table `devices_meters`:

| id | device_id | meter_id | reading | activated_utc_at | deactivated_utc_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 23 | 1.36 | 2018-10-01 15:34:23 | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | 17 | 2.45 | 2019-06-12 18:21:12 | NULL |
| 3 | 6 | 17 | 2.45 | 2019-06-12 18:21:12 | NULL |

`devices_meters` links the device to a meter location. The activated and deactivated dates will sequence the history of the device to meters.

The `status` for each device can be one of:

```
active, online, offline, inactive, retired
```

I have been trying to generate a column `status` with a `CASE` statement to flag each row as one of the above. The query runs, but the resulting data is not as expected.

My `CASE` statement is:

```
   CASE
        // Device retired boolean column flag set to true
        WHEN devices.retired = true
            THEN 'retired'

        // Device with null serial number
        WHEN devices.retired = false
            AND devices.serial_number IS NULL
            THEN 'inactive'

        // Device has not reported back last 24 hrs
        WHEN
            devices.retired = false
            AND MAX(device_measurements.reported_utc_at) < :yesterdayFilter
            THEN 'offline'

        // Device has reported back last 24hrs and has non zero readings for data in this period
        WHEN
            devices.retired = false
            AND MAX(device_measurements.reported_utc_at) BETWEEN :yesterdayFilter AND :nowFilter
            AND SUM(device_measurements.flow) > 0
            THEN 'active'

        // Device has reported back last 24hrs and has all zero readings for data in this period
        WHEN
            devices.retired = false
            AND MAX(device_measurements.reported_utc_at) BETWEEN :yesterdayFilter AND :nowFilter
            AND SUM(device_measurements.flow) = 0
            THEN 'online'

    END AS status,
```

`:nowFilter` contains a date of `now()` in UTC.

`:yesterdayFilter` contains a date of `now()->subHours(24)`.

The above does not fail but returns unpredictable results, such an offline device which has had a data report less than 24 hrs ago.

The whole query is:

```
select
    "devices".*,
    CASE
        WHEN devices.retired = true THEN 'retired'
        WHEN devices.retired = false
        AND devices.serial_number IS NULL THEN 'inactive'
        WHEN devices.retired = false
        AND MAX(device_measurements.reported_utc_at) BETWEEN :yesterdayFilter AND :nowFilter
        AND SUM(device_measurements.flow) > 0 THEN 'active'
        WHEN devices.retired = false
        AND MAX(device_measurements.reported_utc_at) BETWEEN :yesterdayFilter AND :nowFilter
        AND SUM(device_measurements.flow) = 0 THEN 'online'
        WHEN devices.retired = false
        AND MAX(device_measurements.reported_utc_at) < :yesterdayFilter THEN 'offline'
    END AS status,
    MAX(device_measurements.reported_utc_at) AS last_reported_utc_at
from
    "devices"
    left join "devices_meters" on "devices_meters"."device_id" = "devices"."id"
    left join "device_measurements" on "device_measurements"."device_id" = "devices"."id"
group by
    "devices"."id"
having
    (
        CASE
            WHEN devices.retired = true THEN 'retired'
            WHEN devices.retired = false
            AND devices.serial_number IS NULL THEN 'inactive'
            WHEN devices.retired = false
            AND MAX(device_measurements.reported_utc_at) BETWEEN :yesterdayFilter AND :nowFilter
            AND SUM(device_measurements.flow) > 0 THEN 'active'
            WHEN devices.retired = false
            AND MAX(device_measurements.reported_utc_at) BETWEEN :yesterdayFilter AND :nowFilter
            AND SUM(device_measurements.flow) = 0 THEN 'online'
            WHEN devices.retired = false
            AND MAX(device_measurements.reported_utc_at) < :yesterdayFilter THEN 'offline'
        END
    ) = :status
order by
    "devices"."installed_at" desc
limit
    10 offset 0;
```

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your help! I think my issue stems from the CASE whereby the `Sum` piece relative to the `Date Between` is not working as I would expect. Essentially I get data but not the data I expect to get! I suspect this line is the issue -: `WHEN devices.retired = false AND device_measurements.reported_utc_at BETWEEN :yesterdayFilter AND :nowFilter AND SUM(device_measurements.flow) > 0 THEN 'active'` Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Your ***actual*** table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) showing data types and constraints would be the beeline to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a couple of educated guesses, this might be the query you actually want:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT d.*
        , CASE
           WHEN d.retired               THEN 'retired'
           WHEN d.serial_number IS NULL THEN 'inactive'
           WHEN sum_flow > 0            THEN 'active'
           WHEN sum_flow = 0            THEN 'online'
           ELSE                              'offline'
          END AS status
        , m.last_reported_utc_at
   FROM   devices d
   LEFT   JOIN (
      SELECT device_id
           , max(reported_utc_at) AS last_reported_utc_at
           , sum(flow) FILTER (WHERE reported_utc_at BETWEEN :yesterdayFilter AND now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS sum_flow
      FROM   device_measurements
      GROUP  BY device_id
      ) m ON m.device_id = d.id
   ) sub
WHERE  status = :status
ORDER  BY installed_at DESC
LIMIT  10
OFFSET 0;
```

#### Major points

`CASE` statements are processed from left to right. Assuming `retired` is `boolean NOT NULL`, repeating `devices.retired = false` in every following `WHEN` clause is just noise. [Consider the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

> `CASE` clauses can be used wherever an expression is valid. Each
> condition is an expression that returns a boolean result. If the
> condition's result is true, the value of the `CASE` expression is the
> result that follows the condition, and the remainder of the `CASE`
> expression is not processed. If the condition's result is not true,
> any subsequent `WHEN` clauses are examined in the same manner. If no
> `WHEN` condition yields true, the value of the `CASE` expression is the
> result of the `ELSE` clause. If the `ELSE` clause is omitted and no
> condition is true, the result is null.

You write:

> `:nowFilter` contains a date of `now()` in UTC

So it's not a variable but a constant `now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.
Consider operating with timestamp with timezone instead. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

> `:yesterdayFilter` contains a date of `now()->subHours(24)`

So a timestamp that is less than 24h earlier than `:nowFilter`?

I removed the join to `devices_meters` completely, as it plays no role in the query.

I moved the aggregation into subquery. That's cleaner and cheaper for the purpose. Consider:

- [Slow queries related to subqueries using aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54719/slow-queries-related-to-subqueries-using-aggregation/54722#54722)

You seem to want the sum of `flow` for the given time interval, *not* the sum total of all rows. I achieve that with an aggregate `FILTER` clause. See:

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

But you seem to want the latest `reported_utc_at` *overall*, so no filter there.

I wrapped it all in a subquery and added an outer `WHERE` clause to replace the much more verbose `HAVING` clause. `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT`, and `OFFSET` after that, to get 10 rows for `LIMIT 10`.